# How can i show multiple routes in Angular

Tags: angular, routes, binding

In my project, I set 2 routes as `login` and `dashboard`. While the `localhost/dashboard` route works, the login route does not. Where do you think I might be going wrong?

here is `login.component.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  form = new FormGroup({
    username : new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
    password: new FormControl(null, Validators.required)
  });

  constructor(private authService : AuthService, private router: Router) { }

  submitForm(){
    if(this.form.invalid){
      return;
    }
    this.authService
      .login(this.form.get(['username'])?.value, this.form.get(['password'])?.value)
      .subscribe((response) => {
        this.router.navigate(['/dashboard'])
      })
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

login.component.html

```
<div class="container mt-5">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-5">
      <form (ngSubmit)="submitForm()" autocomplete="off">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Kullanıcı Ad</label>
          <input matInput type="username" formControllerName="username" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email" name="username">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Şifre</label>
          <input matInput type="password" formContollerName="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <br>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Giriş Yap</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule  } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    DashboardComponent,

   ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path : 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent
  },
  {
    path: "**",
    redirectTo: 'login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];



@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: is there any error in console? can able to share your code including app.component.html

Comment: You have issues with your `login.component.html` file, what is `formControllerName` in input tags ? 
you have imported `ReactiveFormsModule`, but not providing any `FormGroup` to your `<form>` tag !

Answer (score 0):

### 3 Problems here to correct:

1- It is called `formControlName` and not `formControllerName`

2- `formControlName` MUST be in a parent `formGroup` directive

3- Your default empty route should have a redirection to `/login`. Meaning you need to add this object to the array of routes:

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
```

NB: Additionally your `/dashboard` should be protected by an `authGuard`. As it is your login system is meaningless